# Как поправить алгоритм подсчета цен?

Tags: php, yii2

Цена игры + цена duoq игры = price,
цена победы + цена duoq победы = price,
цена duoq работает отдельно.
На скриншоте наглядно показано[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public function actionPrice()
{
    $divform = new DivisionForm();
    if ($divform->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $divform->proc) {
        $models = Devision::find()->all();
        $k = 1;
        if ($divform->minus != 1) {
            $k = $k * ($divform->proc/100);
        } else {
            $k = $k * ($divform->proc/100);
            $k = 0 - $k;
        }
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            foreach ($model->devisionPrices as $price) {
                $price_game = $price->price_game + $price->price_game * $k;
                $price_win = $price->price_win + $price->price_win * $k;
                $price_duoq_game = $price->price_duoq_game + $price->price_duoq_game * $k;
                $price_duoq = $price->price_duoq + $price->price_duoq * $k;

                $price->price_game = number_format($price_game, 2, '.', '');
                $price->price_win = number_format($price_win, 2, '.', '');
                $price->price_duoq_game = number_format($price_duoq_game, 2, '.', '');
                $price->price_duoq = number_format($price_duoq, 2, '.', '');
                $price->save();
                //var_dump($model->errors);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Может следует добавить что не так? Или нам самим догадаться надо в чём проблема?

Comment: Сейчас суммируется  цена победы + цена duoq победы + цена duoq, а нужно цена победы + цена duoq победы

Comment: Где суммируется? Что мешает суммировать без дуок победы?

Comment: Вы делаете неправильно. Получаете ВСЕ записи из таблицы, потом бежите по каждой и высчитываете поля, а затем сохраняете (кстати говоря в примере нет поля в котором сидит `цена duoq победы`, а на скриншоте названия полей в таблице Вы поменяли на русское название). Либо сделайте функцию на стороне БД которая внутри себя реализует механизм подсчета и обновления записей, что Вы делаете руками - либо напишите `sql`-запрос который будет делать тоже самое. Это будет работать в РАЗЫ быстрее чем считать через `php`